# org-mode source editing indents code after exiting source code block editor

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In org-mode, for the given block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
def hello():
    print('Hello world!')
#+END_SRC
```

[I enter the source code editor with `C-c '`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-source-code.html#Editing-source-code) and the syntax highlighting and indentation and everything else works correctly.

However, after I exit the mode with `C-c '`, 2 spaces of indentation are added so that the source code now appears like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  def hello():
      print('Hello world!')
#+END_SRC
```

How do I fix it so that the indentation is preserved after editing the code block?

Answer (score 4):

You can preserve the indentation after editing a code block in org-mode by setting the following variables (thanks to [Angelo Basile's article, "Org-mode Babel is cool"](https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2016/12/02/org-babel-is-cool/) for the tip):

```
(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 0
      org-src-tab-acts-natively t
      org-src-preserve-indentation t)
```